# Why there are two origin in defining xacro:macro link

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am following the tutorial about urdf. In example 08-xacro, I don't understand why when defining the xacro:macro for a link/visual tag, there are two origin tags before and after geometry tags.

```
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="${wheeldiam/2}" length="0.1"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="black"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </visual>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247151/why-there-are-two-origin-in-defining-xacro:macro-link/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having two origin tags does definitely not make any sense. This is wrong.

Can you link to the tutorial with this error? I didn't find it.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-11-03**:
Here you are
[xacro link](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/blob/master/urdf/08-macroed.urdf.xacro)

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-11-03**:
This is wrong. I have reported it here: https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/issues/22

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-03**:
thanks @David Lu

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-11-11**:
Fixed on Master.

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-11-11**:
Thanks for updating. Can you put this as answer so I can mark question is answered?